# Warlock/cleric vs. warlock/sorcerer?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, cleric, warlock, sorcerer

I'm looking at building a character in 5e D&D but I can't decide which multiclass I would prefer.

My character so far is a 5th level Warlock (Archfey patron, pact of the Tome), and I want to multiclass.

Stats:  STR 11, DEX 14, CON 12, WIS 13, INT 14, CHA 19  (rolled stats)
Variant Human: Actor and War Caster feats.
Invocations: Mask of Many Faces, Aspect of the Moon, and Book of Ancient Secrets.
The rest of the party: Assassin rogue, Glamour bard, Samurai warrior, and Moon druid.

All UA and sourcebooks are allowed, and we are expected to reach level 20 during the campaign.

My overall goal: pure caster, more out-of-combat utility than combat damage.  The character is the party face, and is good at illusion and enchantment magic.

My DM has approved my reasoning for multiclassing, so there is no conflict with Warlock/Cleric. 
I will take Knowledge cleric and/or Favored Soul sorcerer ([from Unearthed Arcana: Sorcerer--the newer, revised one](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/sorcerer)).
The builds I am looking at are the following:

- Warlock 5/Cleric X or Warlock 5/Sorcerer X
- Warlock 8/Cleric X or Warlock 8/Sorcerer X (to get the ASI/feat)
- Warlock 5/Cleric 1/Sorcerer X or Warlock 7/Cleric 1/Sorcerer X

Which of these would be the best given my stated goals?

Comment: OK, beyond clarifying which Favored Soul you are referring to (see the two links in my first comment, please add that clarification per @daze413's comment) having all UA available may increase the scope on optimization options.   I'm off to bed, best wishes ...

Comment: Added in that it's the newer one (from February), hope that clears it up. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Take 1 level of Cleric

With Favored Soul you can cherry-pick the best spells from the Cleric list, all with a much better save DC/attack bonus. You mentioned the spell Command, it matters a lot if the target has to save against DC 12 (Cleric) or DC 15 (Sorcerer).

So why do I still sugget Cleric? Because of the two free skills you get from Knowledge domain, and the Medium Armor poficiency. You could take the medium armor feat, but the +1 Dex would be wasted with your current stats, and Str does not matter to your character at all.

### ASIs are good, and so are 4th level Warlock spells

I would go until level 8 with Warlock, take the level in Cleric and continue as Favored Soul.
Alternatively, your next level could be Cleric already, AC matters even more on the lower levels.